# Is it possible to use cite inside xtable?

Tags: biblatex, knitr, xtable

If I had a table stored in a data frame:

```
library(xtable)
tbl <- data.frame(Name=c("A", "B"),Source=c("\\cite{a}", "\\cite{b}"))
tab <- xtable(tbl)
print(tab)
```

how would I go about producing a tex file that would replace \cite{a} with a bib reference? The final output would look something like:

```
Name Source
A    [1]
B    [2]
```

Unfortunately, knitr by default replaces backslashes with `$\backslash$`. Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function [`print.xtable`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-2/topics/print.xtable), there is different `sanitize` function to add markup in the table. You can have a look at the part *4.1 Markup in table* in the *The xtable Gallery* vignette ( `vignette("xtableGallery")` )

For a `.Rmd` document, this code works:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
tbl <- data.frame(Name=c("A", "B"), Source = c("\\cite{a}", "\\cite{b}"))
xtab <- xtable(tbl)
print(xtab, sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
```
````

output

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & Name & Source \\ 
  \hline
 1 & A & \cite{a} \\ 
 2 & B & \cite{b} \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This solution is very elegant and works beautifully! Many thanks!